# CakePHP - Session being written, then lost on page refresh

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

This is CakePHP 1.3

I have a 5-step order form that stores the new session data after each step.  This works perfectly every step, until the last step where the user completes the order.

On the last step, I save the order, then set a session flag to say it's been completed.  This way, if the user refreshes the page it won't put through another order again.

The problem is, I set the flag in the session and if I debug the session it's there.  On page refresh, the session has reverted completely to how it was before, without the new values.

```
// Controller action for step 5 of the form

public function step5() {

    // FIRST DEBUG
    debug($this->Session->read('order'));

    // Load from session so that the view can display the order information
    $this->data = $this->Session->read('order');

    // Save order if not already completed
    if (!$this->Session->check('order.complete')) {

        // Adds to the database
        if ($this->_saveOrder($this->data)) {

            // Set flag so if the user refreshes, it won't save again
            $this->Session->write('order.complete', true);

            // SECOND DEBUG
            debug($this->Session->read('order'));

        }
    }
}
```

In the first debug when the page loads, the session looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [Order] => Array
        (
            [value1] => 4566
            [value2] => 'test'
            [value3] => 0
            [value4] => 0
        )
    [Customer] => Array
        (
            [fname] => test
            [sname] => test
            [email] => test@torg.co.uk
            [tel] => 0123456789
        )

)
```

Then the second debug shows that the new session flag has been written to the session:

```
 Array
(
    [Order] => Array
        (
            [value1] => 4566
            [value2] => 'test'
            [value3] => 0
            [value4] => 0
        )
    [Customer] => Array
        (
            [fname] => test
            [sname] => test
            [email] => test@torg.co.uk
            [tel] => 0123456789
        )
    ['complete'] => true

)
```

But then if I refresh the page, the `complete` flag is gone, the session has reverted entirely back to how it was before, and the save runs again because the flag isn't there.  There is NO code after the flag is written so it isn't being deleted.

```
Array
(
    [Order] => Array
        (
            [value1] => 4566
            [value2] => 'test'
            [value3] => 0
            [value4] => 0
        )
    [Customer] => Array
        (
            [fname] => test
            [sname] => test
            [email] => test@torg.co.uk
            [tel] => 0123456789
        )

)
```

The session writing works fine on all other steps.  I can add/update session variables between pages and they work fine and persist across pages and page refreshes.

I don't know if this is something to do with my config settings or what.  I don't know why this is happening just on this page.  I also noticed sometimes, very rarely, after tearing my hair out for AGES and clearing the cache a few times, etc. it will seem to briefly work once, then stop working again.

Could it be anything to do with my config settings?  Here is my `Config/core.php` without the comments:

```
Configure::write('debug', 2);

Configure::write('log', true);

Configure::write('App.encoding', 'UTF-8');

Configure::write('App.baseUrl', 'components/com_cake/app');

//Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));

//Configure::write('Cache.disable', true);

//Configure::write('Cache.check', true);

define('LOG_ERROR', 2);

Configure::write('Session.save', 'php');

//Configure::write('Session.model', 'Session');

//Configure::write('Session.table', 'cake_sessions');

//Configure::write('Session.database', 'default');

Configure::write('Session.cookie', 'CAKEPHP');

Configure::write('Session.timeout', '120');

Configure::write('Session.start', true);

Configure::write('Session.checkAgent', true);

Configure::write('Security.level', 'medium');

Configure::write('Security.salt', 'd1a4bfb8a3cxxxxx47173663e9e2e9ea5');

Configure::write('Security.cipherSeed', '1269383xxxxxxxxxx3672219');

Configure::write('Asset.timestamp', 'force');

//Configure::write('Asset.filter.css', 'css.php');

//Configure::write('Asset.filter.js', 'custom_javascript_output_filter.php');

Configure::write('Acl.classname', 'DbAcl');
Configure::write('Acl.database', 'default');

//date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

Cache::config('default', array('engine' => 'File'));
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `$this->_saveOrder`?

Comment: It's pretty epic, to be honest, and doesn't contain anything to do with the session.  A database transaction is started, then it saves the form data to various models, then if everything is good it commits and returns true, otherwise it rolls back and returns false.

Comment: The problem is either `order.complete` is not being persisted correctly, or you're accidentally overwriting it. If you set `badger.complete` (or any unused var) alongside `order.complete` and the two values differ after refresh, you have the latter problem. The former seems odd if your sessions work in many other cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took me absolutely forever to figure out, but the problem was actually that I was using a CakePHP component inside the Joomla framework, and I had to select a different database using PHP's native mysqli functions instead of Cake's database abstraction layer.

What happened was that I changed the selected MySQL database, and this caused loads of subtle and seemingly unexplainable problems that came from Joomla but were only apparent in Cake.

The solution was to ensure that I switched back to the database that Joomla requires, in my `AppController::beforeRender()` method.